# how to get a BlockEntity by position in fabric?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

i am doing a code where i need to get the block entity of a certain location.
something like: `getblockatpos(x,y,z);`
then it returns a BlockEntity

Comment: This question is an example of an XY problem. As shown by your answer, you were trying to get the Block instead of the BlockEntity.

Comment: my original idea was to get the block entity but i had to tweak it to get the material at least (that in my case was fire)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a workaround that does not give me a BlockEntity object, however I can manipulate enough things with it to achieve my result:

`this.world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(this.getX(),this.getY(),this.getZ()))` so is just i do `this.world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(this.getX(),this.getY(),this.getZ())).getMaterial()` to get it's material and `this.world.getBlockState(new BlockPos(this.getX(),this.getY(),this.getZ())).getBlock()` to get the block... same with settings and other blockentity values.